# Using AutoMapper to map a class to enum in c#

Tags: class, enums, automapper

I have the following structure:

```
   public enum ToDoReminderPreset
    {
        [Description("Custom"), CustomText("all"), CustomResxText("ToDoPresetCustom", "PdPlanner")]
        Custom = 0,
        [Description("review my will"), CustomText("will"), CustomResxText("ToDoPresetUploadWill", "PdPlanner")]
        UploadWill = 1,
      //....
     }

 public class TodoPreset
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }  
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public string Description { get; set; } 
        public string GroupName { get; set; } 
        public string LocalizedDescription { get; set; } 
    }
```

I want to map the class to enum. the ID of the class will be the enum value .

```
CreateMap<TodoPreset, Data.ToDoReminderPreset>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (Data.ToDoReminderPreset)(int)src.Id));
```

This is the Error I got when I add the code:

> Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level
>   individual members on a type.

So , how can I map integer property of a class to enum ?**strong text**

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters

Comment: Automapper is not required here `((Data.ToDoReminderPreset)((int)src.Id))` already doing what you need

Comment: or just `CreateMap<TodoPreset, Data.ToDoReminderPreset>().ConstructUsing(s => Data.ToDoReminderPreset)s.Id);`